# How to change the font-size and style of the fallback font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am using 'freestyle script' font to style my site heading and Georgia as the fallback font. I have downloaded the 'freestyle' webfontkit from squirrel and I am using @font-face to render the heading style.
Everything is fine for browsers which support @font-face but for those which do not support @font-face like the default browser of older Android versions, I am facing a problem.

The problem is that with freestyle Script I want to keep the

```
  h1
   {
    font-size:25px; 
    font-style:normal;
   }
```

but with my fallback font ( Georgia ) I want to keep

```
   h1
    {
      font-size:18px;
      font-style:italic;
    }
```

One solution I found on net was to use modernizr...http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-font-face-design-guide
but I am in search of a simpler and no-js solution as my site is already using a lot of js before page load and is getting a bit slow to load due to that

I found a similar question on SO..[Selectively Style Fallback Fonts Without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221975/selectively-style-fallback-fonts-without-javascript)
but there was'nt any clear answer except for the modernizr solution...

It would be great help if someone could give some solution to this problem.

... Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a real problem? Android supports `@font-face` since version 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No approach that I know of that doesn't use modernizer. Stick it in the head of your html. Don't know how people can live without it. To keep it small, use a minimum copy of Modernizer with just the selection for @font-face. Also, if you are on an Apache server, GZIP your html, css, and js by adding a short bit of code to the .htaccess. This will speed you up a lot.

Then do the following:

```
.fontface h1
 {
  font-size:25px; 
  font-style:normal;
 }
```

OR leave the modern browser alone and just do:

```
.no-fontface h1
 {
  font-size:18px; 
  font-style:italic;  
 }
```

[image: Modernizer]

Comment: Thanks cab for the tip about GZIP.I knew about minimal modernizer but was doubtful about using it...It seems GZIP will do the trick..Now I'll go with Modernizer...Kudos :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect font-face support without JS. Easiest way is by far using modernizr as suggested or check [this article](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/) by Paul Irish.

Since `@font-face` has fairly [good support](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face) over desktop browsers I'll go on a limb and assume you need fallback for mobile browsers. If that's the case maybe you should look into server-side detection for mobile browsers (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)).

Lastly, you could try messing around with `font-size-adjust` property ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust) and [article](http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/the-little-known-font-size-adjust-css3-property/)). I never used it before and I can't find out how good is supported across browsers so you'll need to do some testing.

Comment: Thanks Teo for some really nice links... I thought font-size-adjust will be the exact thing I was looking for but alas it is supported only by FF. I can live without italizing my site heading for the small set of browsers not supporting @font-face but font-size-adjust was a must...I wish it was supported by all browsers...ne ways thanks again..SO rocks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Modernizr, I wrote a [stand-alone check that's 2.2KB minimized](https://github.com/RoelN/font-face-render-check) and adds a class to the HTML tag so indicate if `@font-face` is supported. You can then adjust your styles the same way as with Modernizr:

```
.fontfacerender h1
{
  /* special font */
}

.no-fontfacerender h1
{
  /* default font */
}
```